# Groovy code throwing error on jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins

hi i have added the following groovy code in the Post-build Actions of jenkins.

```
import java.util.*
import hudson.model.*

upstreamBuilds = manager.build.getUpstreamBuilds();
upstreamJob = upstreamBuilds.keySet().iterator().next();
lastUpstreamBuild = upstreamJob.getLastBuild();
if(lastUpstreamBuild.getResult().isBetterThan(manager.build.result)) {
lastUpstreamBuild.setResult(manager.build.result);
}
```

but i get the following error when i execute the above code:

```
ERROR: Failed to evaluate groovy script.
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:897)
at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:928)
at java_util_Iterator$next.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:5)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:580)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:618)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:589)
at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuildRecorder.perform(GroovyPostbuildRecorder.java:276)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:710)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:685)
at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.post2(Build.java:162)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:632)
at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1463)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:239)
Recording fingerprints
```

Since i am new to groovy i have no clue how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is because you are calling `next()` on an iterator with no elements in it.

I believe this does the same thing, but handles the `upStreamBuilds` map being empty:

```
upstreamJob = manager.build.upstreamBuilds.find()
if( upstreamJob != null ) {
  lastUpstreamBuild = upstreamJob.key.lastBuild
  if( lastUpstreamBuild.result.isBetterThan( manager.build.result ) ) {
    lastUpstreamBuild.result = manager.build.result
  }
}
```

PS:  You don't need to import `java.util.*` with groovy

Comment: Sorry to say when i use the above code jenkins does not execute the "Groovy Postbuild step". it just ignores the script. Am i missing something?

Comment: Are you sure `manager.build.upstreamBuilds` returns something?  It could be that it's returning an empty map

Comment: actually i see a method as "getUpstreamBuilds()" so i had used it but i am not sure about upstreamBuilds

Comment: Groovy will call `getUpstreamBuilds()` when you access the `upstreamBuilds` property

Comment: ok i am sorry i am very new to groovy. So what do i do now since the above code does not seem to work for me